# Laravel routes issue

Tags: laravel-4

I am trying to render a view when a user enter a particular address.

e.g

`http://localhost/example/public/admin`

what I have tried so far;

```
Route::any('admin', function()
{
return View::make('admin.login');
});
```

and

```
Route::any('/admin', function()
{
return View::make('admin.login');
});
```

the `login.php` in under a folder called `admin` in the `view` folder.

So far, none have worked.

my error:

`Not Found. The requested URL /CoopBooks/public/admin was not found on this server.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve by doing the following.

I found out that `rewrite_module` in Apache was not automatically enabled for `WampServer 2.4`. I have enabled it and it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't need 2 routes to the same address.
`Route::any('admin'..)` and `Route::any('/admin'..)` are the same.

Per your problem, it seems as this is not a Laravel problem and the error is coming directly from your local server (if it was a laravel routing error, you would have received a different error syntax).

In other words, you are accessing the wrong URL. You can see that the error message refers to `/CoopBooks/public/admin` while it needs to refer to `http://localhost/example/public/admin`.
That means that you are either typing in the wrong URL in the address bar, or you somehow changed the `.htaccess` or other Apache directives to direct the user to a different folder.

Make sure your URL is correct and everything should work...

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am using only one of them in each instance. I am typing the address correctly too. It was working until I updated my WampServer this morning.

Comment: I found out that `rewrite_module` in Apache was not automatically enabled for `WampServer 2.4`. I have enabled it and it is working fine. Thanks for the heads up.